# Получение списка SQL-серверов на удаленной машине

Tags: c#, sql-server

Меня интересует, как получить список доступных SQL-серверов на удаленной машине по IP-адресу. То есть, я ввожу IP-адрес узла, а получаю доступные сервера по этому адресу. Может кто знает решение? Буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 3):

То что вы хотите **это не имя сервера**. Это называется **имя ЭКЗЕМПЛЯРА сервера**.

> SQL Server поддерживает на одном компьютере несколько экземпляров компонента Компонент Database Engine, служб Службы Analysis Services и служб Службы Reporting Services. Кроме того, можно обновить уже установленные на компьютере предыдущие версии SQL Server либо установить на этот же компьютер SQL Server.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms143694.aspx

Для того чтобы получить список установленных экземпляров в реестре есть

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL`

где храниться список этих самых экземпляров.

Для того чтобы его получить *удалённо*, необходимо чтобы на сервере работала служба "Удалённый реестр".

Вот [тут](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-SQLInstance-9a3245a0) вам предлагается готовый Powershell скрипт `Get-SQLInstance` для получения информации как о локальных так и о удалённых экземплярах.

Comment: Если вопрос ещё актуален :-))

Answer (score 0):

Просто по открытому порту не удастся определить, какая служба его слушает. Можно соориентироваться на список стандартных портов IANA http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xml
Например, по умолчанию MS SQL сервер слушает порт 1433, а Оракул 2483

Comment: Но тогда я просто узнаю запущен сервер или нет, а мне надо получить имя сервера

Comment: Что такое имя сервера? имя хоста и есть имя сервера

Answer (score 0):

Вам что, по IP надо узнать имя ХОСТА ?

Если так, то в C и С++ см. man 3 gethostbyaddr. В c# видимо тоже есть что-то похожее.

Comment: Я может не совсем ясно описал проблему. Чтобы подключится к sql-серверу необходимо знать адрес машины на котором он запущен и, собственно, имя самого сервера (оно же, на сколько я понял, имя службы), таким образом мы получаем ConnectionString = "server=IP-Address\\SQLSERVERNAME; ...". Дак вот, мне надо узнать SQLSERVERNAME по IP. Я нашел функцию перечисления доступных sql-серверов, но она выдает только доступные локальные сервера (т.е. на которой запущена программа) и, естесственно, для реализации моей задачи не подходит